# Making an interactive calendar in Java

Tags: java, calendar

I am trying to make a calendar in Java. My goal is to make it display the month, day, and year. So far I have been able to do this but I have not made this information fit inside the calendar that I have made. I am really new to this(second week) so I apologize if the code is messy but I really need help!
Here is what I have so far,

CODE:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class realcalendar {

public static void drawMonth() {

for (int w = 1 ; w <= 5 ; w++) { 
      for (int n = 1; n <= 7; n++) {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
      System.out.print("+");
      for (int j = 1; j <=6; j++) {
      System.out.print("-");
}
}
}
      System.out.print("+");
      System.out.println();
      for (int r = 1; r<= 1; r++) {
      for (int t = 1; t<= 3; t++) {        
      for (int y = 1; y<= 8; y++) {
      for (int m = 1; m <= 1; m++) {
      System.out.print("|"); 
      for (int b = 1; b<=1; b++) {
      System.out.print("      ");
}
}
}              
      System.out.println();
}
}
}
     for (int n = 1; n <= 7; n++) {
     for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
     System.out.print("+");
     for (int j = 1; j <=6; j++) {
     System.out.print("-");
}
}
}
     System.out.print("+");
     System.out.println();
} 
private static int numDays = 0;
private static int h = 0;

public static boolean leap(int year) {

   if(((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)) {
   return true;
}
   else {
   return false;
}
}
public static void firstDayOfYear(int year) {

   int month = 13;
   year--;
   h = (1 + (int)(((month + 1) * 26) / 10.0) + year + (int)(year / 4.0) + 6 * (int)(year / 100.0) + (int)(year / 400.0)) % 7;
   String dayName = "";
   switch(h){
      case 0: dayName = "Saturday"; break;
      case 1: dayName = "Sunday"; break;
      case 2: dayName = "Monday"; break;
      case 3: dayName = "Tuesday"; break;
      case 4: dayName = "Wednesday"; break;
      case 5: dayName = "Thursday"; break;
      default: dayName = "Friday"; break;
} 
}
public static void firstDayOfMonth(int month, int year) {

   if(month == 1 || month == 2) {
   month += 12;
   year--;
}
   h = (1 + (int)(((month + 1) * 26) / 10.0) + year + (int)(year / 4.0) + 6 * (int)(year / 100.0) + (int)(year / 400.0)) % 7;
   String dayName = "";
   switch(h){
      case 0: dayName = "Saturday"; break;
      case 1: dayName = "Sunday"; break;
      case 2: dayName = "Monday"; break;
      case 3: dayName = "Tuesday"; break;
      case 4: dayName = "Wednesday"; break;
      case 5: dayName = "Thursday"; break;
      default: dayName = "Friday"; break;
}  
}
public static void numDaysInMonth(int month, int year){
   int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
   if (month == 2 && leap(year)) days[month] = 29;
   numDays = days[month];
   System.out.println("The number of days in the month is " + numDays);
   System.out.println();
}
public static void printCal(int month, int year){

   String[] monthNames = {"","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
   System.out.println("    " + monthNames[month] + " " + year);
   System.out.println("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa");
   for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
   System.out.print("   ");
   for (int i = 1; i <= numDays; i++){
   System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
   if (((i + h - 1) % 7 == 0) || (i == numDays)) 
   System.out.println();
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {    

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter month (1-12): ");
   System.out.println();
   int month = input.nextInt();
   if(month < 1 || month > 12){
   System.out.println("Invalid month. Valids inputs are 1-12.");
   System.exit(0);
}
   System.out.print("Enter year: ");
   System.out.println();
   int year = input.nextInt();
   if(year < 1753){
   System.out.println("Invalid year. Valid inputs are 1753 and beyond.");
   System.exit(0);
}
   firstDayOfYear(year);
   firstDayOfMonth(month, year);
   numDaysInMonth(month, year);
   printCal(month, year);
   System.out.println();
   drawMonth();
}
}
```

OUTPUT: 
[http://imgur.com/gallery/hLMoO](https://imgur.com/gallery/hLMoO)

What I would like it to look like:
[http://imgur.com/gallery/MtCuMNu](https://imgur.com/gallery/MtCuMNu)

Again, sorry about the code but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two distinct functions writing output one after another. First one is printing actual calendar data, and the second one is writing the "background". With text output you cannot just print one over the other, you have to merge them somehow.

But first I would like to give you some general coding tips that would help in analysing and maintaining your code, then I will propose my answer to the main problem.

it would be easier to analyse your code if all of the variables had a meaningful name or at least a comment on what are they for (for example the 'h' variable - at begginig I had no idea what it is.
Some comments regarding what each of the loops, logical statements and equations are doing could also be helpful.

For the answer.
Please note I was trying to use as much of your original code as I could in order to give you a general idea how your problem can be solved.

My proposition is to first generate an **array** representing the days of the current month and then insert them into the "cells" of output, I will use it instead of your "*printCal*":

```
public static int[][] genCal(int month, int year, int firstDay){
    int[][] calendarData = new int [6][7]; //6 weeks x 7 days of week
    int currentWeek=0;//we are starting populating the calendarData from its first week
    int currentWeekDay= firstDay; //we are starting populating the calendarData with first day of month
    for (int i = 1; i <= numDays; i++){
        calendarData[currentWeek][currentWeekDay] = i;
        currentWeekDay++;
        if ( (i + h - 1) % 7 == 0) {
            currentWeek += 1; //setting row number to the next week
            currentWeekDay = 0; // it's next week so we are starting from it's first day
        }
    }
    return calendarData;
}
```

in order to use it, I need to pass to it *firstWeekDay*, or which day of week the month starts (Sunday being 0, Saturday 6), I slightly modified your *firstDayOfMonth()* to return that value (with your 'h' 0 is assigned to Saturday, but I need first day of the week to be Sunday so I would have to parse it anyway):

```
public static int firstDayOfMonth(int month, int year) {
    if(month == 1 || month == 2) {
        month += 12;
        year--;
    }
    h = (1 + (int)(((month + 1) * 26) / 10.0) + year + (int)(year / 4.0) + 6 * (int)(year / 100.0) + (int)(year / 400.0)) % 7;
    String dayName = "";
    switch(h){
        case 0: {dayName = "Saturday"; return 6;}
        case 1: dayName = "Sunday"; return 0;
        case 2: dayName = "Monday"; return 1;
        case 3: dayName = "Tuesday"; return 2;
        case 4: dayName = "Wednesday"; return 3;
        case 5: dayName = "Thursday"; return 4;
        default: dayName = "Friday"; return 5;
    }
}
```

Now next part of the main problem: we have to edit your *drawMonth()* so it would insert values from the calendar. Your version of the function has some unnecesary loops and isn't too redable so I decided to rewrite it completely.
I used different output format so you have to write it yourself again, but I wrote it (fast scetch really) to give you a general idea on how it could be done:

```
public static void drawMonth(int[][] calendarData) {
    for (int[] week : calendarData) { //for each row (week) of the month
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                System.out.print("=====");
            System.out.println();
            for (int day : week) //for each day of the week
                if (day!=0) System.out.printf("|%2d  ", day);
                else System.out.print("|    ");
            System.out.println("|");
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        System.out.print("=====");
}
```

In order to navigate '*calendarData*' array I used foreach loops, but you can do it with a plain old for loop if you prefer.

finally, you must glue it together in your main method, for example by adding something like this at the end:

```
    int firstDay = firstDayOfMonth(month, year);
    int[][] calendarData = genCal(month, year, firstDay);
    drawMonth(calendarData);
```